# SwiftUI - Color Picker/Dynamic Coloring of ZStack

Tags: swiftui

(NewBie in SwiftUI: trying some code here...)
I am trying to dynamically change the color of the ZStack based on a color a user picks from the color picker. Obviously my way of passing the value of the selection to fill the zstack color is problematic. Can you please help in terms of what would the best way to do something like this. Thank you in advance !

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorSelected = Color.yellow
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
      
        ColorPicker("Select Color", selection:$colorSelected)
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                   **.fill(Color.$colorSelected)     (THIS IS THE LINE GIVING THE ERROR)**
                   .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                   .cornerRadius(25.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close!  Instead of trying to access `Color.$colorSelected`, which doesn't exist (`colorSelected` isn't a property on `Color`), just access `colorSelected` alone -- it's a `@State` property on your `View`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorSelected = Color.yellow
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
      
            ColorPicker("Select Color", selection:$colorSelected)
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(colorSelected)
                   .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                   .cornerRadius(25.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much jnpdx. Your help is most appreciated.